# LMI robustness to small perturbations

Tags: positive-semidefinite, lyapunov-functions, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, i.e., $P=P^\top$ and $\langle Px,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume that, for a certain $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists a $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$PA+A^\top P<2\mu P.$$

Let $F(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be such that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\|F(\varepsilon)\|_2=0$. I would like to prove/disprove the following.

**Lemma.** There exists an $\varepsilon^*>0$ and a $\delta(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{R}$, with $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\delta(\varepsilon)=0$, such that for all $\varepsilon\in(0,\varepsilon^*)$ the following holds:
$$P(A+F(\varepsilon))+(A+F(\varepsilon))^\top P< 2(\mu+\delta(\varepsilon))P.$$

I have tried to prove this result by extending robustness results for $P>0$. However, they all use (at some point in the proof) $P^{-1}$, which is not defined in our case (since $P\geq0$).

Comment: It there perhaps a $P$ missing on the right side of your last inequality?

Comment: Yes there is, just fixed thank you!

Comment: If you take $P=A=[1 \;0; 0\; 0]$ and $F(e)=[ 0 \; e ; 0\;  0]$, $\mu=1$ you have a contradiction, right?

Comment: The $P$ you chose is not symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $A=P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $F(\varepsilon)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \varepsilon \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, but sorry this is a counterexample only if the inequality is non-strict.

Comment: But the strict inequality does not make much sense for semi-definite positive (and not definite): multiply right and left by $v\in Ker(P)\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: How do you define the inequality $PA+A^\top P<2\mu P$? Such that $PA+A^\top P-2\mu P$ is a negative definite matrix?

Comment: And what types of functions are allowed for $F(\varepsilon)$ and $\delta(\varepsilon)$, without singularities and continuous for $\varepsilon\in(0,\varepsilon^*)$?